# Based on elements value the left over element in the array of object should be modified

Tags: javascript

I have array of objects where if I have 4 objects in that if 3 element values are false then the remaining one object should also get false and vice versa.

If 5 elements `3 false` `2 true`, then `no change` in the o/p, if only one element is different from other then the value should modify.

Below is the array:

```
array = [{
    "19714": false,
    "19787": true,
    "19870": false,
  },
  {
    "19716": false,
    "19797": false,
    "19890": false,
    "19891": true,
    "19892": false,
    "19894": false,
  },
  {
    "16789": false,
    "19785": false,
    "19800": false,
    "19370": false,
    "19470": true,
    "19874": false,
  },
];
```

Here in the array the 1st object contains 3 elements in that there are two elements are false and the element which is true should also get false.

Same in second object all elements are false except one value

Below is the O/p:

```
array = [{
    "19714": false,
    "19787": false,
    "19870": false,
  },
  {
    "19716": false,
    "19797": false,
    "19890": false,
    "19891": false,
    "19892": false,
    "19894": false,
  },
  {
    "16789": false,
    "19785": false,
    "19800": false,
    "19370": false,
    "19470": false,
    "19874": false,
  },
];
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What should happen, when all the values are true except one which is false?

Comment: What will be output, if out of 4 objects 2 are true & 2 are false?

Comment: @JagsSparrow in that case it should be same no change

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti in that case it should be true

Comment: @vinuta , what should be the output if out of 5 elements 3 false and 2 true ?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi then the output is same 5 elements 3 false and 2 true no change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If false values are greater than true values then it will return all value as false and if true values are greater than false values then it will return all value as true and if both true and false values are same then there will be no change.

Try this.

```js
var array = [{
    "19714": false,
    "19787": true,
    "19870": false,
  },
  {
    "19716": false,
    "19797": false,
    "19890": true,
    "19891": true,
    "19892": false,
    "19894": false,
  },
  {
    "16789": false,
    "19785": false,
    "19800": false,
    "19370": false,
    "19470": true,
    "19874": false,
  },
  {
    "19714": false,
    "19787": true,
    "19870": false,
    "19788": true,

  }
];

var output = array.map(x => {
  var valuesLength = Object.values(x).length;
  var trueIds = Object.keys(x).filter(key => x[key]);
  var falseIds = Object.keys(x).filter(key => !x[key]);
  
  if (trueIds.length !== falseIds.length && (trueIds.length===valuesLength-1 || falseIds.length===valuesLength-1)) {
    var finalValue = trueIds.length > falseIds.length ? true : false;
    Object.keys(x).forEach(key => x[key] = finalValue);
  }

  return x;
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Is that valid scenario , in question it is mentioned , if out of 4 ,3 are false , make fourth one also false? the condition should also include 1 less that total length .

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi if you check my answer it will cover all the scenario.

Comment: 5 elements 3 false 2 true , what should be the output?

Comment: false should be the output as per op's comment ;)

Comment: As per my understanding if false value count is greater than true value count then it should return false of all value and vice versa.

Comment: Based on the boolean value count, the lowest boolean value count will be replaced with the highest count value

Comment: No where in the comments OP mentioned that .

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi 5 elements 3 false 2 true , then no change in the o/p, if only one element is different from other then the value should modify

Comment: That's what I commented below the question and OP replied the same. More trues one false, OP replied all trues ;)

Comment: @VivekJain no its not on greater or lower, if single value value is different and other elements are same then the single value should also have the same answer

Comment: @Sivakumar Tadisetti , are you clear now? there will be no change in the output .  You asked all true except one , obviously answer is all true, that is what OP mentioned

Answer (score 2):

You can use code like below. Here [`Object.entries(a)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) will return array of `[key, value]` pairs from `object`. Then filter it with `true/false` values and if `length == 1` then update respective value with `a[trueValues[0][0]] = false`.

```
array.forEach(a => {
  let trueValues = Object.entries(a).filter(e => e[1] === true);
  let falseValues = Object.entries(a).filter(e => e[1] === false);

  if (trueValues.length == 1) {
    a[trueValues[0][0]] = false;
  } else if (falseValues.length == 1) {
    a[falseValues[0][0]] = true;
  }
});
```

Try it below.

```js
let array = [{
    "19714": false,
    "19787": true,
    "19870": false,
  },
  {
    "19716": false,
    "19797": true,
    "19890": true,
    "19891": true,
    "19892": true,
    "19894": true,
  },
  {
    "16789": false,
    "19370": true,
    "19470": true,
    "19785": false,
    "19800": true
  }
];

array.forEach(a => {
  let trueValues = Object.entries(a).filter(e => e[1] === true);
  let falseValues = Object.entries(a).filter(e => e[1] === false);

  if (trueValues.length == 1) {
    a[trueValues[0][0]] = false;
  } else if (falseValues.length == 1) {
    a[falseValues[0][0]] = true;
  }
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var array = [{
    "19714": false,
    "19787": true,
    "19870": false,
  },
  {
    "19716": false,
    "19797": false,
    "19890": false,
    "19891": true,
    "19892": false,
    "19894": false,
  },
  {
    "16789": false,
    "19785": false,
    "19800": false,
    "19370": false,
    "19470": true,
    "19874": false,
  },
  {
    "16789": true,
    "19785": true,
    "19800": false,
    "19370": true,
    "19470": true,
    "19874": true,
  },
  {
    "19714": false,
    "19787": true,
    "19870": false,
    "19788": true,

  },
  {
    "19714": false,
    "19787": true,
  }
];

let values = [];
let trueCount = 0;
let falseCount = 0;
let totalArrayCount = 0

array.forEach((item) => {
  values = Object.values(item);
  totalArrayCount = values.length
  // get true's count
  trueCount = values.filter((v) => {
    return v == true;
  }).length;
  // get false's count
  falseCount = values.filter((v) => {
    return v == false;
  }).length;
  // If one of the boolean value count is 1 and object has more than two key-value pairs then only update the object
  if (trueCount === 1 && totalArrayCount > 2) {
    item = updateObject(item, false);
  } else if (falseCount === 1 && totalArrayCount > 2) {
    item = updateObject(item, true);
  }
});

function updateObject(obj, boolVal) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    obj[key] = boolVal;
  }
}

console.log(array)
```

Comment: Yeah @Karan ;) based on OP's comments, I got that in my mind